# Combine duplicate rows into single row based on column value in R

Tags: r, merge, rscript

IN "R" I am trying to combining duplicate rows values into one row seprated by by comma based on column value.
FOR EXAMPLE: In "Name" column same rows are present and in “function” Column have different values In output file the  the duplicate entry of "Name" column in the same row in "function" column.

| Name | function |
| --- | --- |
| A | ANEAMIA |
| B | HEARING |
| A | METABOLISM |
| B | T-cell |
| E2 | Leukemia |

output will be:-

| Name | function |
| --- | --- |
| A | ANEAMIA,METABOLISM |
| B | HEARING,T-cell |
| C | T-cell |
| E2 | Leukemia |

Comment: `aggregate(.~Name, df, toString)` where `df` is the name of your dataframe